# Black screen after coming out of sleep mode Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, screen, sleep

I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for now over 2weeks and every time after I go back from sleep mode, it shows me a black screen. I tried nomode and nouveaumode but everytime my screen is in a low 800x600 resolution and forums tell me to undo nouveaumode.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! You need to disable the secure boot!